# Replace taxonomy permalinks

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks, taxonomy, tags, slug

I have this permalinks settings: `/%postname%/`

I have a custom taxonomy `issue`.

I want replace all my taxonomy links `(site.com/category/wordpress)` to  `(site.com/category/wordpress/issue/any-child)`. Like tags.

Maybe this picture help

[image]

Comment: You are mistaking this website for a free code service provider. You have multiple options: 

1. [Read this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/asking).
2. Hire a professional.
3. Use a search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Custom Post Type Permalinks](http://www.torounit.com/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/) plugin Resolved my problem.

** `taxonomy` substitute `post_type`

**Mybe any one the result needs**,

[image]

My impression employee:

**Example**- `post_type: book`
`category: history`
`tag: discount`

**1- post_type**: permalink and to filter working.

> www."domain"/book

**2- post_type + category**: permalink and to filter working.

> www."domain"/book/category/history

**3- post_type + tag**: permalink working filter return 404.

> www."domain"/book/tag/discount

**4- post_type + search**: permalink and to filter working.

> www."domain"/book/?s=any+author

**5- post_type + archives**: permalink and to filter working.

> www."domain"/book/2015/12

**6- post_type + authors**: permalink and to filter working.

> www."domain"/book/author/admin

**7- post_type + authors + category**: permalink working filter return 404.

> www."domain"/book/category/history/author/admin

**8- category + tag**: permalink working filter return 404.

> www."domain"/category/history/tag/discount

Answer (score 0):

You might want to taker a look at [add_rewrite_rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) or [add_rewrite_endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint). Then to test, install a plugin called [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/), it'll help you show you if your rules are conflicting.

There are a couple examples in this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/209896/84219).